# Why runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main) always dead-locked when called from main thread?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

According to official documents, `runBlocking` does:

```
Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread until its completion.
```

But I found the new coroutine still can be scheduled in the curent thread. But why when the current thread is `MAIN( I mean, Dispatchers.Main)`, it will be always blocked?

```kotlin
@Test
fun runInMainThreadButNotBlocked() {
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.post {
        val mainTid = Thread.currentThread()
        Log.d("test", "main thread id is $mainTid")
        runBlocking {
            val tid = Thread.currentThread()
            Log.d("test", "runBlocking enter, tid is $tid") // print Main thread
            Log.d("test", "runBlocking leave")
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Test
fun runInMainThreadAlwaysBlocked() {
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.post {
        val mainTid = Thread.currentThread()
        Log.d("test", "main thread id is $mainTid")
        runBlocking(Dispatcher.Main) {  // never enter
            val tid = Thread.currentThread()
            Log.d("test", "runBlocking enter, tid is $tid") // still print main thread
            Log.d("test", "runBlocking leave")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a quirk of Dispatchers.Main re-posting to main looper. If you used Dispatchers.Main.immediate it would go through.

Comment: @Pawel I wouldn't call this a "quirk". This is calling a function that literally says "blocking" inside the main thread - what could possibly go wrong? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on Android, the way Dispatchers.Main works is by submitting its pieces of coroutine to the main thread by posting Runnables, just like you’re doing by calling `handler.post()`. Since `runBlocking` is blocking the main thread and then submits code to the main thread queue, the coroutine can never start running its code because the main thread can never process the next runnable in its queue.

There is also a Dispatchers.Main.immediate that works a little differently. Assuming the coroutine is started in the main thread, it will synchronously start running the first part of the coroutine instead of posting it to the queue. However, if it reaches a suspension point and then returns to Dispatchers.Main within the coroutine, you would be back to your deadlock situation.